# NumPy array fancy indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with a shape of (9099, 2, 26).

From this array I would like to get a new one with a shape of (9099, 2, 1), where the value for the 3rd dimension will be defined by another 1d array (9099,). 
This 1d array each value is actually an index of required value of 3rd dimension in my main array.

So, for example, the 9th element of my main array looks like this:

`In [1]: a[9,:,:]
Out [1]: array([[      0, 1011165, 1098400, 1140065, 1172240, 1203971, 1439189,
        1600540, 2281575, 8888888,       0,       0,       0,       0,
              0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,
              0,       0,       0,       0,       0],
       [ 280000,  263998,  974020,  653653,  888965,  851341,  466195,
         424801,       0, 9999999,       0,       0,       0,       0,
              0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,
              0,       0,       0,       0,       0]])`

The 9th element of 1d array is:

`In [2]: b[9]
Out [2]: 9`

So the 10th element of the desired output should looks like this:

`In [3]: c[9,:,:]
Out [3]: array([[8888888], [9999999]])`

I guess it should be done somehow with fancy indexing?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to achieve. Can you maybe add a code example with reduced array size? Is the index array to be applied to each slice of the 2nd dimension?

Comment: Sorry, for unclean question. I'll clarify it.

Comment: Adding an example would really help in understanding your question. I have the feeling that for each value in the 3rd dimension you want to select a specific index, however the shape of your array is incompatible with the shape of your index array in that case. I would rather expect something like shape `(9099, 2)` for the index array, or do you want it to be applied to each slice of the 2nd dimension? Again, code example clarifies :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
a[np.arange(len(index)), :, index]
```